# select MIN with order by

Tags: t-sql

I have a @Temp table like this:

```
 Id    TypeId
--------------
14892 |   2
14893 |   3
--------------
```

I need to loop through one record at a time like this:

```
declare @Id int = (select MIN(Id) from @Temp)

while @Id IS NOT NULL
begin
    -- Code here
    select @Id = MIN(Id) from @Temp where @Id < Id
end
```

I also need to loop through the records with TypeId descending like this:

```
declare @Id int = (select MIN(Id) from @Temp order by TypeId desc)
```

So when looping through the records I should get 14893 then 14892 in that order. Of course I get this error when using order by:

```
 The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what your problem here is?  Most of the time with SQL, you do not need to use a loop.  You should really try to avoid them if possible.  If you explain more about your problem and what you're actually looking for as output, then it will be much easier to help you.  Can you provide like 5 lines of sample data and what your preffered output should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to do a lot of complicated functions on each record. The result set will be minimal - maximum 10 records. I know looping should be avoided in tsql but sometimes its you're only option.

I ended up doing it this way:

```
while EXISTS (select Id from @Temp) 
begin 
    declare @Id int = (select top 1 Id from @Temp order by TypeId desc)

    -- Complicated functions

    delete from @Temp where Id = @Id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select ID, min(typeID) 
from @Temp  
group by ID
```